# How to structure a data driven site?

Tags: php, xml, web, structure, storing-data

I can't seem to get my head around structuring a data heavy website. I understand you can break up the sections with php, but when it comes to the main content - how do you store that externally, and how do you go about loading it?

If I was to store the the content data in an XML file, if it's storing data only, what if you needed to throw an image in - the XML would dismiss the img markup.

How do ***you*** do it generally?

Comment: Did you check out databases, for example Mysql? Store files in the file system.

Comment: Databases over XML files. And images are typically stored separately. Can you explain what kind of main content you deal with, or why you tended towards xml?

Comment: I'm familiar with databases and Mysql, I mention XML because it's simpler for me to grasp and experiment with quickly. My real question is more geared towards how external data is loaded into the php to be displayed to the user. I'm fine with writing a function to do this, although I'm trying to figure out where the markup goes. I assume the markup is meant to be kept separate from the raw data (eg. about us text, or contact text) but how do you mark it up when you load it in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read any books on data-driven development?  I think you would benefit a lot from reading one.  There are also lots of online sources that cover the basics.

Most people these days store their content (text) in a *relational database* (e.g. **[MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/)**).  How you choose to store data really depends on the situation however; Sometimes a simple flat-file (e.g. *an XML file*) will suffice.  Ask yourself how much content you will have and whether you need to relate data.

As for images, you should **only store the filenames** of images in your database. Keep the images themselves stored as separate files on your filesystem. That is what it's meant for after all.

Comment: I'm familiar with data-driven development and databases, I'm more caught on how this external content data is brought into the site. Lets say I store filenames in the XML, I assume a function would be written to markup the filenames with IMG. But what about if your content data had 'bold', 'strong' or 'heading' tags throughout it. Say each page is slightly different, perhaps the content on one page has more headings - how would you mark this up if the raw data is without markup?

Comment: I guess it depends, but most of the time you will simply store the content, markup and all, all in a single field (or tag).  That includes bold, strong, heading, img filenames, etc.. all right in with the rest of the content.  It largely depends on what you are building though.  For example, if you have a news application, and each article contains a single photo, you might wish to store the filename separately from the the article body and simply generate the markup for displaying the img when somebody views the article.

Comment: But if I'm storing the data in XML wouldn't the img tags be ignored unless it was being stored as CDDATA?

Comment: Well, yes.  However, I'm not attempting to describe how and what you would need to do to setup an XML file for your data.  I'm simply trying to describe data storage in a broader sense, without concern for which data storage mechanism you choose to use.

Comment: Okay, understood. Well say if you were to build a simple page for a small business which had 4 or so sections (about us, portfolio, gallery, contact etc) would you load the data into it for convenience, or just have separate html files? How would you personally go about structuring it and what languages would you use? (would you break it up with php, or use Server Side Includes, store the content seperately etc etc)

Comment: PHP+MySQL. Personally, I'd throw together a quick administration area to manage portfolio pieces, manage gallery albums & photos, and view contact submissions. For such a small site, I probably would not worry about building anything to manage the About Us page. I'd just build it as a separate page in the filesystem (or more technically, it would have its own controller & view [MVC]).  So: Portfolio pieces, albums, photos, contact submissions to **the database**; Static content (About Us) to a **file**.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your wisdom simshaun, much appreciated! Are there any tutorials or books you'd recommend on the subject?

Comment: Are you looking for something that's focused more on concepts or something that you can follow to create a small website?

Comment: You read my mind, all the books I've been reading have been about the separate stages. I'm trying to find a book that takes you through the process of creating a small website - with pages, modules etc - most of the other books only seem to deal with the front page.

Comment: I have not actively looked for any tutorials in a long, long time. However, personally I believe you would be better off using online tutorials since you can just copy/paste and learn faster by experimentation.  Since I haven't looked for any in so long, I can't really give you "recommended" tutorials.  However, you should be able to find decent ones from **[NETTUTS](http://www.nettuts.com)**, **[SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com)**, and as an auxiliary, **[PHPFreaks](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorials/)**